# Functions problem

Tags: derivatives

If $f(x)=x^{10}$, find $f^{(6)} (0.1)$, but the answer claims to be 15. I am wondering the (6) is meaning differentiating 6 times $f(x)$ or function composition? I have tried both methods and none of them seems to work. A million thanks for the solution.....

Comment: Usually means the sixth derivative

Comment: we get $$f^{(6)}(0.1)=15.1200$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $(6)$ notation indeeds stands for 6 differentiations.

The final function is $151200 x^4$ ($151200 = 10 \times 9  \times 8 \times 7 \times 6  \times 5$), and the image of $0.1$ is $15.12$.

Do you need more clarifications ?

Comment: Oh it seems that I forgot to add *5, thanks @_@